# IJulia zoomable svg

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I am using IJulia to display nifty things. Sometimes I have outputs such as SVGs that I would like to get a closer look at. Is there a way to wrap my output to an IJulia notebook cell such that I can use the standard mousewheel zoom and pan?

Answer (score 1):

ImageView offers support for this, but probably won't display SVGs (it's a bitmap application).

Comment: Will ImageView embedd itself in the IJulia cell or pop open an external window?

Comment: External window. It uses Tk for display. A Gtk version will come someday...